# What is a "virtual" gate as defined by Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate

I came across the Qiskit [textbook page](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.RZGate.html) for the R_z gate. It's classified as a virtual gate. What does that mean exactly? How does this gate differ from the R_x and R_y gate?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the main reference for virtual Rz gates: https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00858